# all static methods and private contructor pattern in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class like.

```
class Xyz{

    private static SomeObject abc;

    private Xyz(){
    }

    public static SomeObject method(){
       abc = new SomeObject();
       return abc;
    }
}
```

I will be using the object for different purpose. Is this a correct thing to do in multi threaded environment?

Edit:

I have edited my class like.

```
class Xyz{

    private static SomeObject abc = new SomeObject();

    private Xyz(){
    }

    public static SomeObject method(boolean newone){
       if(!newone)
        return abc;
       else{
        abc = new SomeObject();
        return abc; 
       }

    }
}
```

All the users should be able to use the object returned by method.
Should I make my method synchronized?  I want all users to use same object.

Comment: Are you sure, you don't want [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)? And, in your case, why do you need variable `abc` since you are returing newly created object immediately?

Comment: No, almost certainly not. Why have the static variable at all if you're going to return the `SomeObject` immediately? Generally speaking, mutable shared state like this is a bad idea.

Comment: Make method as synchronised so that only one thread can be called at a time.

Comment: @jonSkeet I want all users to use the same object. The object has an expiration time. So I want to create a new one. How should I model my class?

Comment: @user168983: Well you should put that information in the question, for a start... you hadn't explained that *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static field in your code is pointless. It's only accessible through `method()`, which recreates the field on every call. It could just return a new object every time, without storing in a static field.

If, on the other hand, what you really want is a singleton, then a safe and simple solution is using an `enum`:

```
enum Xyz {
    INSTANCE;

    private final SomeObject abc = new SomeObject();

    public SomeObject method() {
        return abc;
    }
}
```

This will ensure the singleton property of Xyz, but says nothing about `SomeObject`, not about the thread safety of `abc`. To make it safe to use by multiple threads, you would have to make SomeObject thread safe.

Comment: The class will remain stateless in future, So I did not opt for singleton. I removed the static variable.

Comment: I have edited the code. The object `abc` has some data which user uses. But cannot change the data of object.  Is what I am doing now thread safe?

Comment: Based on your update, you need to synchronize. Thread safety is a bigger subject, and it will depend on the implementation of `SomeObject` too